# Не получается вызвать 404 ошибку с представлением, всегда выдает 500 "Страница недоступна"

Tags: php, laravel

Когда я вызываю abort(404) в laravel 5, вместо 404 ответа с представлением, выходит 500 ошибка "Страница недоступна". Вот часть кода из Handler.php отвечающая за это

```
if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
     return response(view('errors.missing'), 404);
}
```

При том такой вариант работает

```
return response('страница не найдена', 404);
```

И вообще вызов любой view не работает, так же не работает редирект.

Comment: [https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#view-responses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#view-responses)

Answer (score 0):

Пример по отправке View из документации Laravel 5.0 версии:

```php
return response()->view('hello')
```